# Recursive method using ArrayLists

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

So I have this method which will take an ArrayList of Integers, I compare between 2 sub arrays and preform some swapping of numbers.

I am comparing the first elements of each sub array which is just the array halved, then swapping the elements if the bigger number isn't in the left subList. after that I want to recursively do the same thing but to the first half.

so if I type 3 5 8 2 1 7 6 4
I want to see this;

[3, 5, 8, 2, 1, 7, 6, 4]

[3, 7, 8, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2]

[8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2]

[8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2]

What I want to be able to do is once I have done what I need to, to the base array, I need to work on the first half of the same array recursively. However when I compile, I get an error saying that I have incompatible types. So I'm assuming the subList function isn't providing me a ArrayList.

Any pointers on gettign this to work correctly?

```
public static void tournament(ArrayList<Integer> players){
int mid = players.size()/2;
    for(int i=0; i < mid; i++){
        if(players.subList(0,mid).get(i) < players.subList(mid,players.size()).get(i)){
            int temp = players.subList(0,mid).get(i);       
            players.subList(0,mid).set(i , players.subList(mid,players.size()).get(i));
            players.subList(mid,players.size()).set(i,temp);    
        }// end if
    }// end for
    System.out.println(players);

    if(players.size() > 2){
        tournament(players);
    }// end if

}// end tournament
```

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're trying to do, but some parts of your code seem needlessly convoluted. For example, `players.subList(0,mid).get(i)` is equivalent to `players.get(i)`; and `players.subList(mid,players.size()).set(i,temp)` is equivalent to `players.set(mid + i, temp)`. No? In fact, I don't see a single place where your use of `subList` *is* accomplishing anything. Also, your recursive call to `tournament(players)` doesn't really make sense, since that will recurse indefinitely (until you get a `StackOverflowException`).

Comment: I am so adding the homework tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I compile, I get an error saying that I have incompatible types. So I'm assuming the subList function isn't providing me a ArrayList.

With the Collections API (of which the `ArrayList` is part), the best-practice is to declare your variables using the generic interfaces: `List`, `Set`, `Map`, rather than their concrete implementations such as `ArrayList`, `HashSet` and `HashMap`.

For example, instead of this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you should do this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you take a look at the JavaDoc for [java.util.List.subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29), you'll see that the method signature is this:

```
List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
```

`ArrayList`, as an implementation of the `List` interface, uses this exact same signature.  Note that the return type is `List`, and not `ArrayList`.  What this means is that `ArrayList.subList()` doesn't have to return you an `ArrayList` (although it could) - it simply has to return you an object that conforms to the `List` interface.

So what is the first step?  Change your method to accept a `List` rather than an `ArrayList`.  (Whatever method calls your `tournament()` initially method can still pass an `ArrayList`.)

```
public static void tournament(List<Integer> players)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so with the help of a little cleaning up from ruakh I have got it working correctly.
Greg Kopff was correct in that I couldn't return the subList as it was an incompatible type, So what I have done is pass two int elements into the method too.

These keep track of where the sub arrays would begin and progressively work their way closer through recursion.

```
public static void tournament(ArrayList<Integer> players, int left, int right){
    for(int i=0; i < right; i++){
        if(players.get(i) < players.get(right + i)){
            int temp = players.get(i);      
            players.set(i , players.get(right + i));
            players.set(right + i,temp);    
        }// end if
    }// end for

    right /= 2;
    System.out.println(players);
    if(right>=1){
        tournament(players,0,right);
    }
}// end tournament
```

Thanks for the help, this is a bit of homework, more personal homework so thanks for adding the tag, I didn't realize, nor did I expect people to give me the correct answer, just a guide as I knew I had to complete this with what I had learned so far. Thanks all for the help!